# How do I exclude the top and bottom 5% of column in a data frame in r?

Tags: r

If my data frame is called "houses" and I want to exclude the top 5% and bottom 5% of the column Sale_Price, how do I do that?

```
houses[quantile(Sale_Price, c(.05, .95))
```

I tried this code, but I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some data that I assume is similar to what you have.

```
houses<-data.frame(Sale_Price=rnorm(100,50,5))
```

The code to stay only with the prices between the upper and lower 5 % of the `Sale_Price` values

```
#Calculate 0.05 and 0.95 percentiles
quants<-quantile(houses$Sale_Price, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
#Subset according to the two percentiles
df1 <- houses$Sale_Price[houses$Sale_Price > quants[1] & houses$Sale_Price < quants[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)

houses %>% filter(between(Sale_Price, 
                  quantile(Sale_Price, 0.05), quantile(Sale_Price, 0.95)))
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(houses)
houses[Sale_Price %between% quantile(Sale_Price, c(.05, .95))]
```